# AngularJS - $http.get request gets cancelled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, request

I'm trying to get data from a server in my AngularJS app, using $http.get. But when I execute the request, it seems to get cancelled by something. It happens with every link I use. Local files are working.

Below the code from Controller.js:

```
angular
    .module('schoolApp')
    .controller('configController', [
        'apiService', '$http', function (apiService, $http) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.isActive = isActive;
        vm.addPortal = addPortal;

        ...

        function addPortal() {

             ...

             apiService.getServerData('someUrl', "1.0")
                .then(function (result) {
                    var test = result.data;
                })
                .catch(function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                });

        }

        ...
```

And the Service.js:

```
angular
.module('schoolApp')
.service('apiService', [ '$http', function ($http) {
    var service = {
        getServerData: getServerData,
    };

    return service;

    function getServerData(portalUrl, appVersion) {
       // var url = "http://../.../.svc/GetSetting?alias=...&AppVersion=1.0";
        var url = "http://xml.buienradar.nl";
        //var url = "test.json";
        //var url = "xml.xml";
        // "http://" +
        // portalUrl +
        // "/.../.../.svc/GetSetting?alias=" +
        // portalUrl +
        // "&AppVersion=" +
        // appVersion;
        return $http.get(url);
    }
}]);
```

Executing this code will show the alert("ERROR: " + result) from the controller class. Data from the result:

> result: Object 
>  config: Object 
>  data: null 
>  headers: (c)
>   
>  status: -1 
>  statusText: "" 
>   __proto __: Object

Network in browser shows the call is cancelled:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJoZM.png

More info:
- I'm using Phonegap (tested without and doesn't work either)
- AngularJS 1.4

Comment: Does seem to work over here : http://jsfiddle.net/oqscn97x/

Comment: You're right. So it should be something else than the code that I've written here. But I really can't find the cause of this problem.

Comment: Then update your question with your complete code, because we can't judge anything by these snippets.

Comment: added some extra code, but can't post all of it here.

Comment: I have changed the fiddle to reflect these changes, but the code you added isn't anymore helpfull in finding a solution. http://jsfiddle.net/jsd7f6qy/

Comment: See my answer. Thanks for the help Sonaryr!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the answer. I called window.location.reload() in the same function, and that conflicted. So, now I added it to the .then() function in the request.

Comment: Try not to use `window` if you do have to use it, use `$window` instead